# Test Manager (Azure Test Plans) not accessible from Visual Studio Market Place

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to install Test manager extension for my TFS 2015. I'm admin and was able to get/download Delta copy extension from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) without any issue but not able install Test manager. It says -

> We did not find an organization for which you are an owner or a member.

I've tried using multiple browsers also.[image]

Comment: Do you need to install Test manager alone or configure test setup in TFS? Which TFS version are you using?

Comment: I need to configure test setup and preferring -  Test Manager. I believe its best extension available. Any alternatives, equally good as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test manager provision can be used directly in TFS 2015. Please set/change access levels for your account to Advanced. I suppose currently your account might be listed as basic, check your access level as follows:

> http://yourserver:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses

Change the access to advanced, you are automatically provided/entitled with Test manager provision. I found this article over [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/357037/how-to-install-test-manager-extension-on-tfs.html)